Why are the open-chain and cyclic forms of glucose "in equilibrium"?
Glucose can appear in several different isomers, including an open chain and several cyclic forms. According to Molecular Chemistry of the Cell (5th ed., Fig. 2-18) "The open-chain form of this sugar ... is in equilibrium with the
more stable cyclic or ring form ... ".
I have three related questions:
(1) does this mean that the two forms have the same energy, or just "close enough energy to connect them thermally"?
(2) It seems that the propensity of open chain and cyclic form is different when dissolved in water. Yet I've found no mention of energy release when sugar dissolves in water. How come?
(3) Is there some explanation for the equality / close proximity of the chemical energy of the isomers?
If there's an intuitive explanation, that'd be great. For example, it seems obvious that optical isomers have the same energy (so if the temperature is high enough to overcome the transition energy barrier they could be in equilibrium). But the chain and cyclic form seem too different. Is this "random luck"? (or a not-so-random, selected-for property?) Or is there some hidden symmetry I overlooked?
If there are mathematical models that predict this I'd be happy to get some references.
Thanks!

Look up mutarotation (Wikipedia). Your comment (1) is correct in that thermal energy can surmount the energy barrier but still leaves one form being more stable than the other, i.e. the equilibrium constant is >>1 in favour of the ring form. The basicity of the solution plays a role also.

In solutions of glucose, you will find about 99% is the cyclic form, < 1% is the open form. These two forms are in equilibrium with each other, it is just that one is far more favored. And why do you say energy should be released when glucose is dissolved in water?

In solution, alpha glucose and beta glucose interconvert via the linear form of glucose.

[OP] (1) does this mean that the two forms have the same energy, or just "close enough energy to connect them thermally"?

No, they don't need to have the same energy in order to be in equilibrium. In order for a reaction to be at equilibrium,

All species have to be present
All concentrations have to be constant
The forward and reverse rates have to be the same

"In equilibrium" usually means that they are approaching equilibrium (unless we keep "messing with it", e.g. by adding or removing a species).
This does not mean that species have to be present at the same or similar concentration at equilibrium. However, the rates have to be non-zero, which is probably what is meant with "close enough energy to connect them thermally". You can calculate the equilibrium constant and the free energy difference the usual way if you know the proportion of the various species (the linear form makes up less than 1% in aqueous solution at room temperature), see below.

[OP] (2) It seems that the propensity of open chain and cyclic form is different when dissolved in water. Yet I've found no mention of energy release when sugar dissolves in water. How come?

Single crystals of glucose are either pure alpha or pure beta form, and they are not in equilibrium with the other forms in the solid state. The linear form hasn't been crystallized, as far as I know. With such a small fraction of linear form and with its greater conformational freedom ("floppyness"), it is unlikely to crystallize before the other two forms crystallize. Once another form crystallizes, you lose the linear form, too, as the equilibrium re-establishes. I don't think there is a reason to think that the linear form interacts much more strongly with water (i.e. there is nothing special about the aqueous solution, it is the crystalline state that precludes linear form).

[OP] (3) Is there some explanation for the equality / close proximity of the chemical energy of the isomers? If there's an intuitive explanation, that'd be great. For example, it seems obvious that optical isomers have the same energy (so if the temperature is high enough to overcome the transition energy barrier they could be in equilibrium). But the chain and cyclic form seem too different. Is this "random luck"? (or a not-so-random, selected-for property?) Or is there some hidden symmetry I overlooked? If there are mathematical models that predict this I'd be happy to get some references.

Your intuition about the size of the energetic differences is not bad. There is a small different in free energy (in solution) between the alpha and the beta form (reflected in the 36:64 ratio), which you can explain with axial or equatorial position of the hydroxyl on the anomeric carbon. The linear form has a higher free energy, about a dozen kJ/mol higher, which is about the difference between a better and a worse hydrogen bond. So also not that different, and difficult to rationalize with back-of-the-envelope calculations or discussing average bond dissociation energies and estimating differences in entropy.

First of all, why does this reaction happen? Glucose contains both a carbonyl group and an alcoholic function (in reality more than one). From a chemical point of view, these two functional groups can react giving a hemiacetal or acetal compound. In the specific case, the product is a hemiacetal and its intramolecular nature is the motive why it is so efficient.
Again, the hemiacetal formation is a reversible reaction, that is the hemiacetal is always in equilibrium with the carbonyl and alcoholic reactants. This holds always when there are these two functional groups and it means that the equilibrium constant at the observed temperature allows this equilibrium. In fact, if the $K$ has very high (or very low) value the direct (or reverse) reaction is irreversible.
If we want to discuss about energetics, remember that
$$
\Delta G^0 = - RT \ln K
$$
This relation links the equilibrium constant both to the temperature and the standard Gibbs free energy.
In conclusion, the different species have different energetics, but their difference it is not too high and allows this dynamic equilibrium at room temperature.
You can do a nice parallelism with cyclohexane: if you reduce the temperature, the interconversion between configurations is slower and you can observe it by a NMR experiment.

There need not be energy differences just a low activation energy [consider cyclohexane as you allude to and ammonia]. The chemical potential or free energies of the species in equilibrium are the same: deltaG=0. This includes an energy difference [deltaH] and entropy effect [deltaS or concentration]. An interchange depends on both the energy differences and the activation energy

Sure, the activation energy is low compared to the energy available at room temperature. But the different species are present with different concentration in solution, meaning that some of them are more favorite than other ones at equilibrium. Therefore there is a difference in energy.
